# how does a middleware get deleted?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, middleware, actiondispatch

rack-timeout is included in the Gemfile, but we only want it as middleware on production.  Thus in an initializer, we have:

```
config.middleware.delete Rack::Timeout
```

Inspecting before and after this line shows rack-timeout removed from the array.  Regardless, requests are still timing out, and a quick 'puts' in the gem shows that it is indeed the culprit.

Is this because the middleware stack has already been built before delete is called?  Or is the stack read in every request?  If that's the case, what could be the issue?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Why not just have something like the following?

```rb
group :production do
  gem "rack-timeout"
end
```

In theory, the middleware deletion in the initializer should take care of the problem after a server restart, assuming you're talking about putting something in `config/initializers/`.

---

Did a little more experimentation and dropped this into `config/initializers/rack-timeout.rb`:

```rb
if Rails.env.production?
  Rack::Timeout.timeout = 0.5
else
  Rails.configuration.middleware.delete Rack::Timeout
end
```

And this in a scaffolded controller:

```rb
sleep 1
```

Everything seemed cool after I restarted the dev server (no timeouts in sight :D). So, maybe just a bad variable.

**I still think using a production-only group is the better solution.**

*Ran with Rails 3.2.2 with ruby 1.9.2-p290 on OSX.*

Comment: The project is since done and gone so I can't confirm results, but this looks solid to me!

Comment: I saw a link to this thread on twitter, so I thought I would put an answer on it. :)